# How to get modified lines for renamed file in a commit with git

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I cannot find a git command where I would get the diff for a renamed file in a commit correctly. So lets say we have a look at the repo [pypa/pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) and the commit `d0423ac8a0bdf3454f165eb9871f7b9327f390cb`. If we run the following command on our cloned repo:
`git diff --stat d0423ac8a0bdf3454f165eb9871f7b9327f390cb~1 d0423ac8a0bdf3454f165eb9871f7b9327f390cb` one could see that the file `linux.py` got renamed to `_proc.py`

Unfortunately when I would run `git show d0423ac8a0bdf3454f165eb9871f7b9327f390cb -- pipenv/vendor/shellingham/posix/_proc.py`  the renamed file is treated like a new file and one does not see the true changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try naming the two files :

```
git show d0423ac8 -- pipenv/vendor/shellingham/posix/linux.py pipenv/vendor/shellingham/posix/_proc.py
```

Comment: Yes...that works perferctly...do you have an idea how I could list all files with the renamed ones before and after? Because when I would do `git show --pretty="" --name-only d0423ac8` I would not get the renamed ones before the renaming.

Comment: Nevermind...`--name_status` did the trick for me